# Having trouble printing (java)

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

I am having problem printing the array after changes. The code is supposed to contain an array, and then I insert a number which is supposed to become the index number (this case 4). That number is then taken and moved to the back of the array, while all the other numbers move one index higher up in the array to fill the empty spot. For some reason it doesn´t allow me to print the array after making the changes.

```
public static int SendaAftast(int a[], int i) {
    for(int k = 0; k <a.length; k++) {
        int temp = a[k];

        while(k <a.length) {
            a[k] = a[k] - 1;
        }
        a[a.length] = temp;
    } 
    return a[i];
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = new int [20];
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*a.length)+1;
    }

        System.out.println(SendaAftast(a, 4));
```

Comment: So, what is your problem? The infinite loop? The `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: Sorry, it simply doesnt print anything, although I would like it to print the array after I made the changes

Comment: Note: `a[a.length]`. The first available index for an array is `0`, the last one is `arrayLength - 1`. `a[a.length]` is out of bounds, the last available index is `a[a.length - 1]`.

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Infinite loop

You don't get anything printed because you have an **infinite loop** in your code which is:

```
while(k < a.length) {
    a[k] = a[k] - 1;
}
```

If the condition `k < a.length` is `true` it will always be `true` since you never change its state within the loop in other words `k` is never modified in this loop it is only modified outside and `a.length` never changes either.

#### 2. `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

The second issue in your code is `a[a.length] = temp;` which will throw a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` if reached because the index of an array goes from `0` to `a.length - 1`.

#### 3. The new code of `SendaAftast`

Moreover your method `SendaAftast` doesn't seem to be properly written, as far as I understand your context, it should rather be something like this:

```
public static int SendaAftast(int a[], int i) {
    int temp = a[i];
    // Move everything from i to a.length - 2   
    for(int k = i; k < a.length - 1; k++) {
        a[k] = a[k + 1];
    }
    // Set the new value of the last element of the array
    a[a.length - 1] = temp;
    return a[i];
}
```

Or even faster with a [`System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#arraycopy-java.lang.Object-int-java.lang.Object-int-int-):

```
public static int SendaAftast(int a[], int i) {
    int temp = a[i];
    // Move everything from i to a.length - 2   
    System.arraycopy(a, i + 1, a, i, a.length - 1 - i);
    // Set the new value of the last element of the array
    a[a.length - 1] = temp;
    return a[i];
}
```

#### 4. How to print an array?

To print an array, you must first convert it as a `String` and the easiest way to do it, is with `Arrays.toString(myArray)` so you can print it like this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static int SendaAftast(int a[], int i) {
    int temp = a[i];
    for (int k = i; k < a.length-1; k++) {
        a[k] = a[k+1] ;
    }
    a[a.length - 1] = temp;
    return a[i];
}
```

Your SendaAftast should look like this. The inner while loop was useless,and also the reason for your the infinite loop that made your program not print. Also variable 'a' cannot be indexed by its own size as counting in an array starts from 0 - a.length-1,hence to get the last value of the array you should use a[a.length-1] and not a[a.length].

Answer (score -2):

Change the line:

```
a[k] = a[k] - 1;
```

to

```
a[k] = a[k-1];
```

Bye!

Comment: And why does that fix the infinite loop or the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`?

Comment: You should put some effort into explaining *why* your solution fixes the OP's problem, which generally means that you should also explain the actual problem.

Comment: You're right. That was the first comment, I'll do better next time!